# AspectJ LTW not working with JMX remote

Tags: java, aspectj, jmx

I tried to do a simple project (hello world) with a simple aspect. I use Maven to build this project, LTW for the aspect, logback for the logs.
The aspect is weaved when I use:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\java"
  -javaagent:.\libs\aspectjweaver-1.7.3.jar
  -cp ".\libs\ProtoApp-v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;.\libs\*"
  -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
  -Daj.weaving.verbose=true
  -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true
  -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:.\logback.xml
org.iiter.continuum.protos.simple.App
```

But when I add parameters for JMX, the aspect is not weaved anymore:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\java"
  -javaagent:.\libs\aspectjweaver-1.7.3.jar
  -cp ".\libs\ProtoApp-v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;.\libs\*"
  -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
  -Daj.weaving.verbose=true
  -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7777
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:.\logback.xml
org.iiter.continuum.protos.simple.App
```

I can’t figure what’s happening, if any of you could help me.

The options for JMX remote I added are:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7777
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

NB: I tried for an OSGI app (equinox) and it works fine with this parameters for JMX, but I really need for a regular Java application.

**Edit 1**

I added a Java Agent to inspect the classloaders.

When I activate JMX remote, the classloaders hierarchy is (containsConfiguration means that Aspectj configuration is found by java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)):

```
- root
  - AdaptorKey [sysHashCode=1672527304, loaderClass=javax.management.remote.rmi.NoCallStackClassLoader, containsConfiguration=false, hasParent=false]
  - AdaptorKey [sysHashCode=1040288884, loaderClass=sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader, containsConfiguration=false, hasParent=false]
  - AdaptorKey [sysHashCode=239625678, loaderClass=sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader, containsConfiguration=false, hasParent=false]
  - AdaptorKey [sysHashCode=1818873899, loaderClass=javax.management.remote.rmi.NoCallStackClassLoader, containsConfiguration=false, hasParent=false]
  - AdaptorKey [sysHashCode=527532737, loaderClass=sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader, containsConfiguration=false, hasParent=false]
    - AdaptorKey [sysHashCode=132787710, loaderClass=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader, containsConfiguration=true, hasParent=true]
  - AdaptorKey [sysHashCode=426901684, loaderClass=sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader, containsConfiguration=false, hasParent=false]
```

Whithout JMX remote activated, the classloaders hierarchy is:

```
- root
  - AdaptorKey [sysHashCode=527532737, loaderClass=sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader, containsConfiguration=false, hasParent=false]
    - AdaptorKey [sysHashCode=132787710, loaderClass=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader, containsConfiguration=true, hasParent=true]
```

With this results… I still don’t understand what’s happening. The configuration is found by my agent but not by Aspectj…

In the logs I see that AspectJ register no other classloader but javax.management.remote.rmi.NoCallStackClassLoader.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution: I need to add “**-Xbootclasspath/p:libs/aspectjweaver-1.7.3.jar;libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar**” to my command line.

With this option, everything work fine.

The full command line is:

```
java
    -javaagent:.\libs\aspectjweaver-1.7.3.jar 
    -Xbootclasspath/p:libs/aspectjweaver-1.7.3.jar;libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar 
    -cp ".\libs\ProtoApp-v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;.\libs\*" 
    -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7777 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    -Daj.weaving.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true 
    -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:.\logback.xml 
    org.iiter.continuum.protos.simple.App
```

Thanks to Andy Clement for his help

Tugdual

Comment: This solution is only a workaround. This bug has been resolved in AspectJ 1.7.4: [Bug details](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415266)